# Single instance of a helper object with parameters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

One of our projects makes use of key-value pairs where certain runtime parameters - that do not change per instance of the program - determine the value gotten. For example:

**Program run in `test` mode with the parameter `"Municipal"`**:

```
Key: "testMunicipalDirectory"
Value: "C:\Foo\Bar\"
```

**Program run with the parameter `"State"`**:

```
Key: "StateDirectory"
Value: "C:\Bar\Baz\"
```

To make it slightly more complicated, if there is no matching key for, say `"testMunicipalImagesDirectory"`, there is a fallback of `"defaultImagesDirectory"`:

```
Key: "testMunicipalImagesDirectory" ?? "defaultImagesDirectory"
Value: "C:\Foo\Bar\Images" ?? "C:\Images"
```

Currently, there's a lot of code duplication/inefficiencies, and room for error. Every time one of these is referenced there's string concatenation and null-coalescing and other stuff going on.

It seems like this would benefit from a single-instance object that is passed certain parameters on initialization (`test` or not, `"State"` or `"Municipal"`, etc), that will return the correct values for each different property the keys represent.

Many answers I found to questions asking how to use the singleton design pattern with parameters basically boil down to "if it uses parameters, you probably do not want a singleton". In my case, it is invalid to attempt to initialize the object with different values, and an exception should be thrown if this happens.

This is how I would accomplish this goal (pseudo-C#) (lazy-loading is not a requirement but is used here):

```
public sealed class Helper
{
    // how can we enforce that Init has been called?
    private static readonly Lazy<Helper> lazyLoader = new Lazy<Helper>(() => new Helper(name, test));

    public static Helper Instance { get { return lazyLoader.Value; } }

    public static void Init(string name, bool test)
    {
        // if it has already been initalized
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This has already been initalized.");
        // else initalize it
    }

    private string Name { get; set; }
    private bool   Test { get; set; }

    private Helper(string name, bool test) { } // assign to properties, any other ctor logic

    public string Directory
        { get { return ValueGetter.Get((this.Test ? "test" : "") + this.Name + "Directory"); } }
}

public static class ValueGetter
{
    public static string Get(string key, string fallbackKey)
    {
        if (Keys.Any(k => k == key))
            return Keys[key].Value;
        else
            return Keys[fallbackKey].Value;
    }
}
```

But as you can see, there are questions remaining. How can it enforce calling `Init` before using the `Instance`, but not require those parameters to be passed *every* time `Instance` is accessed?

Is this the correct direction to go, or is there a better design pattern to use?

Comment: Maybe dependency injection can help you with this?

Comment: I don't know a lot about dependency injection. Would you be able to give a brief example how it could be used in this way?

Comment: DI is simply injecting any required data into your object. Whatever data you are initializing should be initialized *before* the object is created, then injected/passed into the object (possibly via a constructor). You'd If initialization fails, the object shouldn't be created, thus preventing the issue of using the object before initialization. Instead of making `Init` static, have a lazy call to it when "gettinf" the instance.

Comment: Okay, that (DI) makes sense. And that's basically what I'm doing/need to happen here. The values used by the `Helper` class are passed into it, rather than determined inside it. With "have lazy call to it...", then wouldn't I have to pass in those values every time I got the instance?